# How to retrieve boolean variable using mysqli in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assigned_project_tester` (
  `Assigned_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Project_manager` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tester_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Test_creation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Test_execution` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Assigned_id`)
)
```

Here are two field named Test_creation and Test_execution which stores boolean values  I want to print 'yes' or 'no' on basis of value stored in the database.I dont know how to retrieve boolean values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
        include 'footer.php';
        include 'config.php';

        $sqluser = "SELECT * FROM user_master where Username='meet.patel'and Role='Tester' ";
        $result = $conn->query($sqluser);
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        }

        $sql1 = "SELECT Project_id FROM assigned_project_tester  where Tester_name IN (SELECT Username FROM user_master where Username='meet.patel') ";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        ?>

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">View Profile</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills">

                            <li class=><a href="#profile-pills" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#project-assigned" data-toggle="tab">Project</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#change-Password" data-toggle="tab">Change Password</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-pills">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead>

                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Username:</td>
                                                    <td><b> <?php echo $row['Username'] ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Full Name:</td>
                                                    <td><b> <?php echo $row['Full_name'] ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Email: </td>
                                                    <td><b><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Contact no:</td>
                                                    <td><b> <?php echo $row['Contact_no'] ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Role: </td>
                                                    <td><b><?php echo $row['Role'] ?></b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="project-assigned">


                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>

                                                    <th>Working for Project</th>
                                                    <th align="center" colspan="2">Permission</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th>Creation of Testcases</th>
                                                    <th>Execution of Testcases</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>

                                                <?php
                                                    $i = 1;

                                                    while ($store = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                        $proid = $store['Project_id'];
                                                        $sql4 = "select Project_title from project_master where Project_id='" . $proid . "'    ";
                                                        $resultprot = $conn->query($sql4);
                                                        $sql5 = "select Test_creation,Test_execution from assigned_project_tester where Project_id =' " . $proid . "'   ";
                                                        $resultper = $conn->query($sql5);

                                                        while ($rowse = $resultprot->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                            echo '<tr><td><b>' . $i . '&nbsp;' . $rowse['Project_title'] . '</b></td></tr>';
                                                            $i++;
                                                            if (!$resultper) {
                                                                echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
                                                                exit;
                                                            } else {
                                                                $rowper = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                                                $a = $rowper['Test_creation'];
                                                                $b = $rowper['Test_creation'];
                                                                if ($a == 0 && $b = 1) {
                                                                    echo 'execution permission assigned';
                                                                } elseif ($a == 1 && $b = 0) {
                                                                    echo 'creation permission assigned';
                                                                } elseif ($a = 1 && $b = 1) {
                                                                    echo 'both permission assigned';
                                                                } else {
                                                                    echo 'No permission assiged';
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.panel-body -->

                                <!-- /.panel -->


                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="change-Password">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                                <form action="changePassword.php" method="POST" role="form">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label>Current Password</label>
                                                            <input class="form-control" name="curr" type="password"
                                                                id="curr" required="required" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label>New Password</label>
                                                            <input class="form-control" name="newpass" type="password"
                                                                id="newpass" pattern=".{6,}"
                                                                title="Must Contain Six or more characters"
                                                                required="required" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                                            <input class="form-control" name="confirmpass"
                                                                type="password" id="confirmpass" pattern=".{6,}"
                                                                title="Must Contain Six or more characters"
                                                                required="required" />
                                                        </div>

                                                        <button type="submit" name='submit' class="btn btn-primary"
                                                            id="submit">Change Password</button>
                                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                                <?php
                                                    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                                                        $curr = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'curr'));
                                                        $new = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'newpass'));
                                                        $confirm = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'confirmpass'));
                                                        if ($new == $confirm) {
                                                            $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE login SET password = ? WHERE Username=? ");
                                                            $sql->bind_param('ss', $new, $_SESSION['username']);
                                                            if ($sql->execute()) {
                                                                $sql->close();
                                                                echo 'Password Updated Sucessfully';
                                                            } else {
                                                                $sql->close();
                                                                echo "Error:<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Password doesn't match";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">

                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <b></b>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!--<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <!--<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` types are an alias for `TINYINT(1)` so if you insert `true` or `false` in the database you'll get an 1 or 0.

If you want to retreive values as yes or no, you'll need to do it with an `if`

```
$myBool = "";
if($result['Test_creation'] == 0){
  $myBool = "no";
} else {
  $myBool = "yes";
}
```

You can also directly put it into the query with `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Test_creation <> 0 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END
```

Comment: can i write $value=$result['Test_creation']??Does it save $value equal to either 0 0r 1

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
<?php  $query = "SELECT Test_creation, Test_execution FROM assigned_project_tester";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($row['Test_creation'] == 0){
                  $val = "no";
                } else {
                  $val = "yes";
                }
    }
    $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();?>
```

Comment: It is not working @Ayyanar...I am trying with  foreach getting some unexpected result..Please can you help me???

Comment: can i write $value=$result['Test_creation']??Does it save $value equal to either 0 0r 1......I am putting code it seem to complex because i am using other fields of tables to get required fields......

Comment: I have updated the question and added code kindly check reply me soon Thanks in advance @Ayyanar G